# GET method (failed) sometimes on a link

Tags: web-server

We just moved to a new server, and our page sometimes doesn't load.
When I check Inspect elements, and look at the network tab, some element gets cancelled and sometimes the entire pages fails to load.

I am quite new to this, and never seen this sort of behaviour before. Anyone has any tips to pinpoint the problem ?

Comment: Oh, ok. cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly: obtain the web server error and access logs and compare those with what you requested.

Comment: I run nginx on the front end the apache at the back. As in, nginx is listening on the port 81, and redirecting everything to port 80. apache is listening on the port 80. Ip tables is redirecting all incoming traffic from port 80 to 81. So its like 80-iptables->81-nginx->80-apache->content

Comment: I will grep the name of the element that failed/canceled from the apache and nginx error logs.

Comment: So i have checked, and none of the error logs have any record of that picture that did not load.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily convoluted; I would suspect the nginx proxy if there is nothing in the apache error logs.

Comment: I have changed nginx logs to debug, expecting to find anything that causes it. I have also increased nginx workers, but nothing changed. Still no idea why the problem occurs.

Comment: ok, i did find the error now, gonna edit the post.

Comment: Ok, so I figured all put. Gonna update my original post.